# RTL content entry in Sitecore

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, arabic

This is a question which partly stems from my lack of linguistic understanding of Arabic and other RTL languages.

I'm working on a Sitecore site which now requires localisation for RTL languages. The specification states that all text elements should be right aligned, and of course the dir="rtl" attribute applied.

However, what I can't readily find out is whether the Sitecore Content Editor (not just the WYSIWYG control, but all input fields) should be switched to RTL and how to do this. Creating an Arabic version of an existing item does not change input fields to RTL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the Sitecore Client doesn't support RTL.

If you are worried about that you will have invalid data on the front end - don't worry. RTL just changes the flow of the text and will have no impact on how your content editors enter their content. You can see what I mean here - http://jsfiddle.net/dgtbw4m5/2/

```
<label for="rtlInput">RTL Input:</label>
<input type="text" id="rtlInput" dir="rtl" />
<br/>
<label for="ltrInput">LTR Input:</label>
<input type="text" id="ltrInput" />
```

Test the two inputs and you will see it won`t make much difference for the content editor as the only thing changing is the text flow is a different direction. The value remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I guess I'm more concerned about the experience for the authors than anything, and that's where my lack of understanding of Arabic leaves me feeling a bit exposed! I didn't want a nightmare scenario where they have to write backwards, for example.

Comment: @grumpyoldcoder RTL will be the eternal challenge for the web :)

Answer (score 4):

The Rich Text Editor will automatically switch to RTL in the editor and any text entered will be right aligned, but the input boxes and other controls will not. You can still enter arabic text in those controls but it will simply be left aligned. As long as your front-end code has the correct RTL tag set then it will render to the end user correctly.

Also remember you have the Page Editor at your disposal and you should build your site with this in mind, using the Page Editor even the simple text fields will be RTL.

Comment: Thank you for the additional insight @jammykam and useful to know that Page Editor fully supports RTL.

Answer (score 0):

when content is mixed with any RTL Language and English, the content got messed up with different order. Because, English locale by default Left to right. To avoid that follow the *"dir"* tag for English content.

Use span tag surrounded English work with dir="RTL" < span dir = "RTL" > English < / span >

أواجه مشك**English**ال محتوى ممزوج باللغتين الإنجليزية والعربية.